# Error in migration - Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

Cant undestand what wrong with syntax sql file migration. please, help:

i run rake db:migrate

error:

**Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1: UPDATE photos SET votes_count = 0, rating = 0 WHERE id NOT IN ()/home/user/myapp/appmame/db/migrate/20131110162613_recalculate_photos_rating.rb:8:in `up'**

```
class RecalculatePhotosRating < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    if Vote.where("subject_type='Photo' and rating > 1").count > 0
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "DELETE FROM votes WHERE subject_type='Photo' AND rating <= 5"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE votes SET rating=1 WHERE subject_type='Photo'"
    end
    pids = Vote.where(subject_type: 'Photo').pluck(:subject_id).uniq
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE photos SET votes_count = 0, rating = 0 WHERE id NOT IN (#{pids.join(', ')})"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE photos SET rating=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.subject_type='Photo' AND subject_id=photos.id) WHERE id IN (#{pids.join(', ')})"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE photos SET votes_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.subject_type='Photo' AND subject_id=photos.id) WHERE id IN (#{pids.join(', ')})"
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the `pids` query returns empty result:

```
class RecalculatePhotosRating < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    if Vote.where("subject_type='Photo' and rating > 1").count > 0
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "DELETE FROM votes WHERE subject_type='Photo' AND rating <= 5"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE votes SET rating=1 WHERE subject_type='Photo'"
    end
    pids = Vote.where(subject_type: 'Photo').pluck(:subject_id).uniq
    unless pids.empty?
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE photos SET votes_count = 0, rating = 0 WHERE id NOT IN (#{pids.join(', ')})"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE photos SET rating=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.subject_type='Photo' AND subject_id=photos.id) WHERE id IN (#{pids.join(', ')})"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE photos SET votes_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.subject_type='Photo' AND subject_id=photos.id) WHERE id IN (#{pids.join(', ')})"
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Comment: I inserted unless pids.empty? and again same error.